# Whenever I hit run eclipse it gives value of previous run program

Tags: java, eclipse, run-configuration

Earlier when i am creating a new class for practicing programs in Eclipse. I use to create in same project and it used to run well. But lately i have to specially go to Run>Run Configuration> I have to manually select the project and main class.

Is there any configuration i m missing as this is time consuming to every time go and change the main class.

Can anyone help?

Comment: usually static void main method is executed when u hit run button

Comment: I understand that, but even if it is there in each program. Still it is returning value of previous run program

Comment: click on class in report explorer and then click run

Answer (score 0):

You can press the black arrow near the Run button to select what to run, usually you will find your classes with `public static void main(String[] args)` there. That's how it works for me.

[image: Run button]

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be due to new class files not being generated due to errors. I have seen the same results as you (new changes not picked up) due to one or both of the following.

1) Look for red-! or red-X next to a project and fix the problem(s) in that project.

[image]

2) Check the Problems tab and fix all red-X errors.

[image]